# Get List of Site Collection under Content Database

Tags: site-collection, content-database

Is there a way I could view the list of Site Collection under a specific Content Database?

Doing it one-by-one on Central Admin is not desirable since there's a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep!

`(Get-SPContentDatabase DatabaseName).Sites`

That will output a list of URLs.

Comment: Thanks Trevor! that did the trick!